# CSS grid: fit vertical span automatically

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid with 24 columns, an outside margin of 1vw, and a gap of 1vw. This is:

`100vw` - `1vw` * 2 margin - `1vw` * 23 gaps = `75vw`. `75vw` / 24 = `3.125vw` for each square.

Now I have two elements. I want them to be in the center, at `grid-column: 10 / span 4;`.
I want them to take the necessary blocks automatically, but cant find the way.

```css
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 3.125vw);
        margin: 1vw;
        padding: 0;
        grid-auto-rows: 3.125vw;
        gap: 1vw;
      }

      .main {
        grid-column: 10 / span 4;
        border: 2px solid;
      }

      .sub1 {
        grid-column: 10 / span 4;
        border: 2px solid;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="main">
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sub1">
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
        <div>item</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If I force the row blocks they take with `grid-row: 1 / span 5`, for example, it will work,of course. But I cant do that, as I don't know the height of the items in advance.

Is there any way to solve this with my grid?

Thanks!

Comment: @mahan you can click on «run code snippet»

Comment: ` grid-auto-rows: minmax(3.125vw,max-content);` and margin instead gap ?  can you clarify your example , because here you only have 2 cells in your grid, there will be more should we guess? for the spanning rows, JS will help you retrieve the height and set a value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think something like this is possible using only CSS, a while back there was a similar question but I don't think there were any satisfactory answers / or any answers and after looking for it a lot I didn't find anything other than it may be available in future. Here I found this [CSS Box Alignment Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/) regarding aligning in grid. See if its relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking for a simple native css way to do this. If thats not possible I will modify my layout, no issues with that.

It is surprising that this is not possible with only css, this is the best use case I can find for css grid.